# What is the name of this irrational math constant and is there a compact way to write it? 0.10110111011110...

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I think this number is a transcendental number and I've tried looking online to see who first made it, I'm not sure if it's a Liouville Number or if there is a more common or better name for it.  Does .10110111011110111110... have a name and is there a compact way to write it using math symbols?

Comment: Subtract it from 1/9 = 0.1111111... and express the resulting pattern of ones by the according negative powers of 10

Comment: The sequence of digits appears at https://oeis.org/A023532 and the number with this sequence as digits was referred to by the symbol $\alpha$ by Harold M. Stark in his book, An Introduction to Number Theory.  I don't know it is important enough to have received a name or a reserved character, we use $\alpha$ for several other things.

Comment: Following Helms suggestion above: $1/9 - \alpha = 0.01001000100001\ldots = 10^{-2} + 10^{-5} + 10^{-9} + 10^{-14} + \ldots + 10^{-n(n+1)/2+1}+ \ldots$ so $\alpha = 1/9 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty 10^{-n(n+1)/2+1}$. This is a sum with general term roughly on the form $x^{n^2}$. Such sums can usually be expressed via non-elementary functions called [theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function).